# Can not import class after added in build.gradle.kts

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I generated spring boot kotlin project with spring initializer in intellij.

And added lib dependency in build.gradle.kts after auto generated.

Implementation `"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"`.

I tried import `WebSecurityConfigureAdapter`, but intellij is 'No suggestions'.

I could not import class after added in build.gradle.kts.

And i tried Run Configurations build, buildDependents, clean, etc...

How can I fix?

Comment: Did you tried reimporting gradle dependencies?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem could be, because you have not shown your `build.gradle`.

Comment: I fixed 'Reimport All Gradle Projects' in intellij. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Kotlin Gradle DSL](https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-build-logic-from-groovy-to-kotlin/#configurations-and-dependencies) specification. Use

```
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.2.6.RELEASE")
```

to declare dependencies.